# How i concatenate the text in 3 files and put in fourth file

Tags: bash, unix

> Hello
>
> This what i want to happen

F4 = f1+f2+f3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the standard unix way is 
  cat f1 f2 f3 > f4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on *inx OS:

cat file1 file2 file3 > file4